# What happens when php://temp is opened more than once?

Tags: php, file

If the `php://temp` (or `php://memory`) file is opened more than once, will the handles point to the same file? Or will each handle be unique?

*I couldn't find an answer in the php docs, so I'm going to [write up a test script to find out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719376/what-happens-when-php-temp-is-opened-more-than-once/7719432#7719432).  I figured it's worth asking here so someone else can find the answer easily.*

Comment: What do you think are file-handles for?

Comment: @hakre But if I opened `./data/test.txt` twice, I'd be working with the same file - right?

Comment: Which isn't documented as well, right? ;)

Comment: @hakre In most of the other situations it seems obvious - a file in the file-system would be the same data, `php://output` would be the same stream, this is the one case where it *seems* like it should be different (each 'open' to be unique), but since it's the one that's different, I don't think it's immediately obvious. And I don't mind testing, but figured this would be nice if anyone else wonders the same thing.

Comment: I think it's okay to ask, and nice to see your feedback :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each handle points to an independent stream. Example:

```
$a = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');
$b = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');

fwrite($a, 'foo');
fwrite($b, 'bar');
 
rewind($a);
rewind($b);

$a_text = stream_get_contents($a);  //=> "foo"
$b_text = stream_get_contents($b);  //=> "bar"

fclose($a);
fclose($b);
```

This is not *explicitly* documented anywhere, but it is implicit in the documentation for streams and wrappers.

From the official [php documentation on streams](https://www.php.net/streams) in general, it is clear that for the standard case of streams, each file handle is associated with it's own independent stream.

And in the [documentation on IO stream wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php), it lists the possible wrappers noting exceptions as they occur. There is an exception listed for the first three (stdin, stdout, stderr):

> php://stdin, php://stdout and php://stderr allow direct access to the
> corresponding input or output stream of the PHP process. The stream
> references a duplicate file descriptor, so if you open php://stdin and
> later close it, you close only your copy of the descriptor-the actual
> stream referenced by STDIN is unaffected.

But no such exception is listed for `php://temp` or `php://memory`. Hence it follows that these would work like normal independent streams.

Also, there are some comments on these pages that further imply the Independence of these streams.

Comment: Indeed. Just tested and found that out - any link to that documented someplace?

Comment: It's at least not said anything else, but as that was no answer to you, well, you needed to check :)

Comment: @hakre Yeah, it seemed like that's what it should do - but I think it should be documented someplace.

Comment: @TimLytle, it is documented. I'll update my post with the relevant docs.

Comment: @TimLytle, I do agree that the docs are kind of vague on this point though, and that logical reasoning doesn't always apply to the php api. So hakre's suggestion of submitting a doc improvement is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

My test code:

```
$f1 = fopen('php://temp', 'rw');
$f2 = fopen('php://temp', 'rw');

fputs($f1, "File One");
fputs($f2, "File Two");

rewind($f1);
echo "First line from F1: ";
echo fgets($f1) . PHP_EOL;
echo "Second line from F1: ";
echo fgets($f1) . PHP_EOL;
fclose($f1);

rewind($f2);
echo "First line from F2: ";
echo fgets($f2) . PHP_EOL;
echo "Second line from F2: ";
echo fgets($f2) . PHP_EOL;
fclose($f2);
```

And results:

```
First line from F1: File One
Second line from F1: 
First line from F2: File Two
Second line from F2:
```